# Xcode malloc error debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging, malloc

I have a large amount of code and it throws the following error/exception.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0xce52964: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

If I run it with all the memory management stuff such as NSZombies and such enabled then it functions perfectly fine.

I added a `Symbolic Exception Breakpoint`of type `malloc_error_break`, and it stops on a random line (an `NSLog(@"part6");` in which I use to help debug my code by breaking it into sections via `NSLog`).

I've also tried typing into the debugger and this is what I get:

```
po 0xce52964
(int) $3 = 216344932 [no Objective-C description available]
```

Does anyone know how I can attempt to further debug this?  I'm not sure what in my code is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable malloc stack logging (which can be done in Xcode - a few checkboxes below zombies).

Then Run/Test your program - Reproduce the issue. Now use the `malloc_history` util to get more info about the allocation which malloc has flagged in the message.

Comment: I turned that on and it says it writes it to the /tmp/ folder.  How do I use "malloc_history"?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/malloc_history.1.html